# gdb failing in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gdb, scons, eclipse-cdt

Here is the tool stack:  Installed on Windows 7 (x64) is Eclipse (Juno x64) with CDT and the [SConsolidator](http://sconsolidator.com/) plugin.  Underneath is the [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download) (x64) bundle installed with 64-bit support.

If I build a 64-bit application and debug it using Eclipse (which uses gdb bundled with GCC), it builds without error and debugs fine.

When I build a 32-bit application and try to debug it with Eclipse, it builds fine but gdb fails:

```
gdb: unknown target exception 0x4000001f...
```

Debugging it with the same gdb via command line works fine.

Any ideas on how to work around this?

FYI: Here are some warnings leading up to the gdb exception:

```
warning: `C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll': Shared library architecture i386:x86-64 is not compatible with target architecture i386.
warning: `C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64.dll': Shared library architecture i386:x86-64 is not compatible with target architecture i386.
warning: `C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64win.dll': Shared library architecture i386:x86-64 is not compatible with target architecture i386.
warning: `C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64cpu.dll': Shared library architecture i386:x86-64 is not compatible with target architecture i386.
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for ntdll32.dll.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for WOW64_IMAGE_SECTION.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for WOW64_IMAGE_SECTION.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for NOT_AN_IMAGE.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for NOT_AN_IMAGE.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
```

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem in a different scenario but i think the solution should be applicable here too.

I was gdb.exe downloaded from http://www.equation.com/servlet/equation.cmd?fa=gdb to debug a C++ program.
I first tried the 64-bit because my pc is 64-bit but I got the same error as Paul got above. Then I tried 32-bit gdb.exe and it worked.

I also followed the links that were given by Paul and there was also bundle available for 32-bit. So I assume the bundles depend on the type of application rather than the configuration of the platform. But, I doubt 64-bit bundle will work on 32-bit architecture. I haven't tried that and can't say for sure.

I suggest install the bundles that support 32-bit to debug a 32-bit application.